# How to drag and drop ul > li elements in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

In the system, there are two areas to be considered in automating drag and drop functionality. One thing which called "timesheet" is in the `div` and another one is in `ul > li`. Here is the timesheet html sample,

```
<div class="time-update__top-block">
```

In the test scripts, I used this way to drag and drop as follows,

```
cy.get(".time-update-block", { timeout: 60000 })
      .trigger("mousedown", { force: true })
      .wait(2000);
    cy.get(
      '.anotherElement',
      { timeout: 60000 }
    )
      .trigger("mousemove", { force: true }, "topLeft")
      .wait(2000);
    cy.get(
      '.anotherElement',
      { timeout: 60000 }
    )
      .trigger("mouseup", { force: true }, "topLeft")
      .wait(2000);
```

Above code was executed successfully and the element was dragged and dropped in the way I wanted.

Other one's html sample as follows,

```
 <ul class="schedule-movie-list">
    <li class="undefined schedule-movie-list__item " title="Drag me!" draggable="true">Name1</li>
    <li class="undefined schedule-movie-list__item " title="Drag me!" draggable="true">Name2</li>
    <li class="undefined schedule-movie-list__item " title="Drag me!" draggable="true">Name3</li></ul>
```

In the test scripts, I used this way to drag and drop as follows,

```
cy.get(".schedule-movie-list > .schedule-movie-list__item", {
      timeout: 60000
    })
      .eq(1)
      .click()
      .trigger("mousedown", { force: true });

    cy.get(
      '.anotherElement2',
      { timeout: 60000 }
    ).trigger("mousemove", { force: true }, "topLeft");
    cy.get(
      '.anotherElement2',
      { timeout: 60000 }
    ).trigger("mouseup", { force: true }, "topLeft");
```

But eventually above code was not executed successfully. The element was not dragged and dropped automatically. If anyone has an idea to resolve this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dataTransfer` const, we can get what we need to achieve;

```
describe("Main Page", () => {
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer;
  it("Drag & Drop elements", () => {
      cy.get('.schedule-movie-list > .schedule-movie-list__item')
        .first()
        .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer });

      cy.get(schedulerPerformancePanel)
        .first()
        .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer })
        .wait(3000);
```